# How plausible are non-hostile mimics?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

Can I have an area with non-hostile mimics who actually will help the party for a one-use-a-day perk?

Or is that too far-fetched and and immersion-breaking for players?

Comment: Is this a custom world or are you using a module/existing 5e setting?

Comment: From what I understand from the question, it's opinion-based. It depends completely on how your **players** view mimics. You might want to describe your problem rather than the solution, i.e. what are you trying to accomplish by giving them a friendly mimic?

Comment: @HellSaint Mind that the Primarily Opinion-Based reason to hold a question is about the answers here being necessarily mostly opinion (which is why “it’s up to the GM” and similar question situations don’t qualify under POB). Do you see that potentially happening here?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I do think both answers here, as currently written, are more opinion-based than experience-based or backed up by official text. I don't think the answers would **necessarily** be opinion based, but I think the question can be improved so we get less of them, at least. The first thing I would improve is what I mentioned: actually stating what OP wants to accomplish.

Answer (score 7):

The answer to this is wholly dependent on the setting. Is this meant to be true to the books as written? Then likely not.

However!

If you're the DM and you decide that this is plausible behavior for mimics in your world, then yes, you can definitely have an area with non-hostile mimics.

The important thing here is that you're consistent. As long as you're consistent (perhaps by presenting the players with mimics in a number of situations, all or most of whom are helpful), consistency should set the tone. While it might be jarring for those familiar with mimics from previous games, your setting and consistent portrayal should offset immersion "breaks" and keep this from seeming like a *deus ex machina*.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.se :) - while I agree with your answer, you could back it up. You mention it's not likely to be consistent with RAW, so you could quote the mimic flavor text, emphasizing what you think is relevant to argue. Note that the MM entry on mimics has a line that actually disagrees with you - ", a rare few evolve greater cunning and the
ability to carry on simple conversations in Common or
Undercommon. Such mimics might allow safe passage
through their domains or provide useful information in
exchange for food. "

Comment: For your second part of the answer, you could exemplify with scenarios you have actually played that were consistent inside the world, although they were against what players would usually expect, and how that didn't break the immersion or at least wasn't enough to take out the fun (of a party that seems to be interested in immersion).

Answer (score 4):

Mimics are very stupid creatures with an INT of 5.  As such, their reasons for doing anything are on par with most animals, and they will not be compelled to converse with, least of all work with, anything they can devour.

However, if your world contains a *variant* of a mimic that has a bit more intelligence and can actually understand a language, then please use it.  After all, it is your world and you can place any creature you want within it.

Comment: Ogres have an int of 5 as well... for comparison.

Comment: Also, just because they are dumb, it doesn't mean they are hostile to everything. Horses have lower ints than mimics and can be friendly to PCs. Even wolves or other primarily aggressive animals can.

Comment: Isn't animal intelligence still considered to be 1-3?

Comment: @Ifusaso it is. I think he meant it's "closer to an animal" than an human (average 10 int).

Comment: Yes, I did mean 'closer to an animal'.  Also, mimics have that INT of 5 because they are able to figure out a good thing to mimic and a great place to do it for maximum benefit.  Which, in the mimic's world, is unwary food.  OTOH, I did essentially say that the DM has every right to do whatever in their worlds.